# How to add characters to strings of differing sizes in preparation for joining data frames via left_join?

Tags: r, dplyr, gsub

I have a base df titled `help.a` and I am attempting to join `help.b`, however, when I read in `help.b` the id variable is numeric and not the same length/format as the id variable in `help.a`. I am attempting to stick with character variables due to left_join changing them to character when the levels of the factor are different.

```
help.a <- data.frame(id = as.character(c("00005", "00010", "00010", "00010", "00025", "00025", "00324", "00324")),
                       var_a = c(NA, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                       var_b = c(4, NA, NA, 4, 4, 4, NA, NA))

help.b <- data.frame(id = c(5, 10, 324),
                         var_c = c(2, 2, 2),
                         var_d = c(4, NA, 6))
```

My approach thus far has been to change help.b to a character, however, it fails to join due to the ids not matching:

```
help.b$id <- as.character(help.b$id)
left_join(help.a, help.b)

     id var_a var_b var_c var_d
1 00005    NA     4    NA    NA
2 00010     2    NA    NA    NA
3 00010     2    NA    NA    NA
4 00010     2     4    NA    NA
5 00025    NA     4    NA    NA
6 00025    NA     4    NA    NA
7 00324    NA    NA    NA    NA
8 00324    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

This is my desired end result:

```
     id var_a var_b var_c var_d
1 00005    NA     4     2     4
2 00010     2    NA     2    NA
3 00010     2    NA     2    NA
4 00010     2     4     2    NA
5 00025    NA     4    NA    NA
6 00025    NA     4    NA    NA
7 00324    NA    NA     2     6
8 00324    NA    NA     2     6
```

And what I think I need to do is read in `help.b` and change id to a character and then add "0's" to each id, but all need to equal 5 characters in length... e.g., row 1 would need four "0's" and row 2 would need three "0's". That way the left_join will notice matching strings and join appropriately.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for `sprintf`:

```
help.b$id <- sprintf("%05d", help.b$id)
```

With the `d` you indicate that you want to format integer numbers, with the `05` that you want the resulting number to be 5 characters wide padded with zeros.

From the comments it appears that `help.b$id` is a character column. In that case, depending on the platform (on linux this doesn't work; the help filt of `sprintf` doesn't tell on which platforms this works), you can use

```
help.b$id <- sprintf("%05s", help.b$id)
```

Or,

```
# When help.b$id is a character use
id <- as.numeric(help.b$id)
# When help.b$id is a factor use
id <- as.numeric(as.character(help.b$id))

# Just to make sure check the conversion went ok; should return empty vector and
# if not the values for which the conversion went wrong.
help.b$id[as.character(id) != help.b$id]

help.b$id <- sprintf("%05d", id)
```

Comment: I want to add the 0's to the `help.b` df though... and when I use that command I get an error saying 'Error in sprintf("%05d", help.b$id) : 
  invalid format '%05d'; use format %s for character objects'

Comment: And when I run that above command... It changes the ids to sequential 00001, 00002, 00002, 00002, 00003, etc.

Comment: Ok, the help.a$id is a factor. And this probably also means that is contains values that are not numbers. Try changing `%05d` into `%05s`.

Comment: Correct... help.b$id <- sprintf("%05s", help.b$id) worked... Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up `help.b` and `help.a` in my answer. This is now corrected. The solution with `%05s` doesn't seem to work on all platforms. I also added a solution which should work on all platforms.

Answer (score 2):

One option here is to simply convert the `help.a$id` column to numeric, and then use the baseR `merge()` function in `LEFT JOIN` mode (`all.x=TRUE`):

```
> help.a$id <- as.numeric(as.character(help.a$id))

> merge(help.a, help.b, by="id", all.x=TRUE)
   id var_a var_b var_c var_d
1   5    NA     4     2     4
2  10     2    NA     2    NA
3  10     2    NA     2    NA
4  10     2     4     2    NA
5  25    NA     4    NA    NA
6  25    NA     4    NA    NA
7 324    NA    NA     2     6
8 324    NA    NA     2     6
```

**Update:**

If, for some reason, you want to retain the original column, then just create a copy of it in the `help.a` data frame, e.g.

```
help.a$id_orig <- help.a$id
```

Do this before converting `help.a$id` to numeric.

Comment: The dataset I'm working with has over 100,000 rows and when I switch to numeric something screwy happens. Separate of that, I am hoping to keep the variable in factor/character format for future operations in the script.

Comment: Then create a backup of the column and call it `help.a$orig_id`.  What does "something screwy" mean?  I don't see a problem with converting a single column to numeric (through character).

Comment: Good question :) I have additional dfs to merge into the main df and there seems to be a few extra thousand observations that are duplicate. I can attempt to diagnose that problem and use the numeric route.

Comment: So in this case, a backup of the column would allow me to compare to the numeric column? Thanks for the help with this.